# React Native app with context - Search and Report functionality

Tags: react.js, react-native

I have a react native app. I have a search component, that I reuse in the SearchScreen (where I search for train stops) and again in my Report screen where I report (and first search station) not station with issues. I was trying to apply best practices but not sure how well I did. I would really appreciate some advice!! Thanks!!!
PS. Im sorry for so much code, last time I posted here I was told its not stackoverflow so I should post all the code. I hope its alright and one or the other would still look over it. Many thanks in advance!!!

1. I am reusing the Search (component), however, I had to do many things to be able to do so. I wonder if I forced the reusability too much/if I should only reuse my SearchBar component, have some duplicate code but define differences in SearchScreen and ReportScreen so its more clear because even if SearchScreen and ReportScreen both use Search, there are differences (what happens on submit etc)?
2. How consistent should I be with keeping state in context? So far I only keep train stations that I fetch on mount. I dont need more. For example: I dont store searchResults in context store. I only iterate through the fetched stations and once I find by id, I use local setstate.
3. For clearing inputfield, I am using custom hook as if I had it in my context store, I would also need to store form input there and that I beliebe should be local. I also couldnt keep it local as I am needing it in multiple components. However in my SearchBar Component I also have a clear function because I also need to show/calcel buttons etc, not only clear input field. What is your opinion here?
4. After I search,I am being redirected to other screen: SearchResultsScreen. When I use the go back button in navigation header, I want to be able to see the old state (the input the user typed and the autocomplete suggestions open. Since I reuse the search component and dont want this behavior to exist everywhere (I dont want it in reportScreen where I reuse search) and did not know how to do it differently so I am passing isRestoreCurrentSearchState prop for when I want the old state to 'come back'. In my navigation I pass option  unmountOnBlur: true, because I dont want the pre state in any other case. Thoughts?

**services/StationsAPI.js**

```
let StationsAPI = {
    fetchStations: () => {
        return axios.get(`${api_root_url}/stations`)
            .then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        })
    },

    updateStation: (updateProp) => {
        return axios.put(`${api_root_url}/report`, updateProp)
            .then((res) => {
                return res;
            })
    }
};
```

**context/SearchContext**

```
const searchReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'fetch_stations':
            return {...state, stations: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const fetchStations = dispatch => async () => {
    const stations = await StationsAPI.fetchStations();
    dispatch({type: 'fetch_stations', payload: stations})
};

export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
    searchReducer,
    {fetchStations},
    {stations: []}
)
```

**context/createDataContext.js**

```
export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
    const Context = createContext();
    const Provider = ({children}) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue)
        const boundActions = {};
        for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    };
    return { Context, Provider};
};
```

**screens/SearchScreen.js**

```
const SearchScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [clearSearch, handleClearSearch] = useClearSearch();

    const onSubmit = (id) => {
        handleClearSearch(false)
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        navigation.navigate('SearchResults', {id: id});
    };

    return (
        <View>
             <Search
                 isRestoreCurrentSearchState={true}
                 handleClearSearch={handleClearSearch}
                 clearSearch={clearSearch}
                 onSubmit={onSubmit}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

**components/Search.js**

```
const Search = ({handleClearSearch, clearSearch, onSubmit, isRestoreCurrentSearchState}) => {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] =  useState([]);
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
    const {fetchStations, state} = useContext(SearchContext);
    const { stations } = state;

    useEffect(() => {
        const stations = fetchStations();
        setData(stations);
    }, []);

    const updateSearch = item => {
        setSearchInput(item);
        setDisplay(false);
    };

    const restoreCurrentSearchState = () => {
        setSearchInput(searchInput)
        setDisplay(true);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (id) => {
        if (isRestoreCurrentSearchState) {
            restoreCurrentSearchState();
        }
        onSubmit(id);
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <SearchBar
                display={display}
                setDisplay={setDisplay}
                searchInput={searchInput}
                onInputChange={(input) => setSearchInput(input)}
                handleClearSearch={handleClearSearch}
                clearSearch={clearSearch}
            />
            <AutoComplete
                display={display}
                setDisplay={setDisplay}
                searchInput={searchInput}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                updateSearch={updateSearch}
                suggestions={stations}
            />
        </View>
    )
};
```

**components/SearchBar.js**

```
const SearchBar = ({ handleClearSearch, clearSearch, setDisplay, searchInput, onInputChange}) => {
    const onChange = (input) => {
        onInputChange(input)
        if (input) {
            onInputChange(input)
            setDisplay(true);
            handleClearSearch(true)
        } else {
            setDisplay(false);
            handleClearSearch(false)
        }
    };

    const cancelSearch = () => {
        setDisplay(false);
        handleClearSearch(false);
        onInputChange('');
        Keyboard.dismiss();
    };
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={[styles.inputWrapper, clearSearch && styles.pressedIn]}>
            <View>
                <MaterialIcons name="search"/>
            </View>
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Search"
                value={searchInput}
                editable
                onChangeText={onChange}
            />
            {clearSearch &&
                <MaterialIcons
                    name="cancel"
                    onPress={cancelSearch}
                />
            }
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

**components/AutoComplete.js**

```
const AutoComplete = ({display, searchInput, updateSearch, suggestions, onSubmit}) => {
    const onPress = (item) => {
        updateSearch(item.name)
        onSubmit(item._id)
    };

    const renderSuggestions = suggestions
            .filter(({ name }) => {
                const match = name.substr(0, searchInput.length);
                return match && match.toLowerCase() === searchInput.toLowerCase();
            })
            .map((item) => {
                return (
                    <View key={item._id}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(item)}>
                            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text>{item.trainType}{item.lineNum}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )
            });

    return (
        <View>
            {display &&
            <View>{renderSuggestions}</View>
            }
        </View>
    )
};
```

**screen/ReportScreen.js**

```
const ReportScreen = () => {
    const [report, setReport] = useState("");
    const [isReported, setIsReported] = useState(false);
    const {state} = useContext(SearchContext);
    const [searchResultId, setSearchResultId] = useState('');
    const [clearSearch, handleClearSearch] = useClearSearch();

    const onSubmitReport = () => {
        return StationsAPI.updateStation( {
            id:searchResultId,
            isReport: true,
            report: {info: report}
            }).then(() => {
            setIsReported(true)
        })
    }
    const getSearchResultId = (id) => {
        setSearchResultId(id);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            {isReported ? <ReportSuccessMessage /> : (
            <>
            <Text>Report Station</Text>
            <Search
                handleClearSearch={handleClearSearch}
                clearSearch={clearSearch}
                onSubmit={getSearchResultId}
            />
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="report"
                    value={report}
                    editable
                    onChangeText={(value) => setReport(value)}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                <Icon.Button
                    name="report"
                    onPress={onSubmitReport}
                >
                    <Text>Report</Text>
                </Icon.Button>
            </View>
                </>
                )}
        </View>
    )
}
```

**screens/SearchResultsScreen.js**

```
const SearchResultsScreen = ({route}) => {
    const {state} = useContext(SearchContext);
    const { stations } = state;
    const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState(null);
    const { id } = route.params;

    useEffect(() => {
        const result = stations.find(station => station._id === id);
        setSearchResult(result);
    }, [])

    const getClosestStation = (order) => {
        const {closestStations} = searchResult;
        const id = closestStations.id[order];
        const result = stations.find(station => station._id === id);
        setSearchResult(result);
    };

    const watchStation = (station) => {
        return WatchListAPI.addStationToWatchList(station);
    };

    const renderComponentContent = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <Station searchResult={searchResult}/>
                <ReportInfo
                    searchResult={searchResult}
                />
                <AddToWatchList
                    searchResult={searchResult}
                    watchStation={watchStation}
                />
                <ClosestStationNav
                    searchResult={searchResult}
                    getClosestStation={getClosestStation}
                />
            </>
        )
    }
    return (
    <View>
      {searchResult ? renderComponentContent() : null}
    </View>
    )
}
```

**components/ClosestStationNav.js**

```
const ClosestStationNav = ({getClosestStation, searchResult}) => {
    return (
        <>
        <View>
            {searchResult.closestStations.id && (
            <View>
                <Ionicons
                    name="arrow-back-circle-outline"
                    onPress={() => getClosestStation(0)}
                />
                <Text>Nearest Station</Text>
            </View>
            )}
            {searchResult.closestStations.id && (
                <View>
                    <Ionicons
                        name="arrow-forward-circle-outline"
                        onPress={() => getClosestStation(1)}
                    />
                    <Text>Nearest Station</Text>
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
        </>
    )
}
```

**useClearSearch.js**

```
export default () => {
    const [clearSearch, setClearSearch] = useState(false);
    const handleClearSearch =  (boolean) => setClearSearch(boolean);
    return [clearSearch, handleClearSearch];
};
```

**I have not included Station, ReportInfo, AddToWatchList Components as there isnt anything 'happening' its just presentational components.**